# Getting tags names of specific tag

Tags: java, xpath

Using XPath.

I have this doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <items>
    <item1>
      <tag1>1</tag1>
      <tag2>DFGGFDGF</tag2> 
      <tag3>3</tag3>
    </item1>

    <item2>
      <tag1>DFGD</tag1>
      <tag2>SDFSDFFSD</tag2>    
      <tag3>SDFSFDFS</tag3>
    </item2>
  </items>
</root>
```

I want to get the tags names of the `item1` element.

Now i use this to get the tags value:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//"+ node_name +"/*/text()");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
}
```

How do i get the tags names: `tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use text() at the end of your XQuery.  You need the nodes themselves.  Second, don't take the node value, you need the node name instead.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//"+ node_name +"/*");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeName()); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give like this

```
xpath.compile("//"+ node_name +"/*")

.......................

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeName()); 
}
```

Comment: you printing nodename or nodevalue?

Answer (score 0):

Try `org.w3c.dom.Node#getNodeName()` to get the name of the node.

Also see ["org.w3c.dom.Node"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)